# When is "did" needed in questions using simple past?

Tags: past-tense, questions

1. Who **did** find my keys?
   is wrong "Who found my keys?" is right

while:

2. Which film **did** you see yesterday evening?
   is right.
3. Why **did** she phone you yesterday?
   is right.

Those are question I answered at face2face course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't just about the past simple tense form but about whether you want to ask about a subject or an object. We usually use the *wh*-words *who, whose, which and what* both as subject and object but with a slight difference. For example:

- Who is the best footballer in the world? (who as subject)
  (**He** is the best footballer because.....)
- Who did you meet? (who as object)
  (I met **Dunken**...)
- What happened after that? (what as subject)
  (**This** was what happened next...)
- What did you say? (what as object).
  (I said that**she left** ...)
- So The question here *Who Did Find My Keys?* is wrong because you ask about the *subject*( suppose the answer is: *Sue found my keys*).
  So "Who Found My Keys?" is correct.